# C# - Adding value to combobox filled with databinding?

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource, default

I'm trying to add default value to my combobox that has been populated with datasource. Check image below:

[Windows form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOj8.png)

Values are automatically added from oracle database. Now what I need to do is add one more, default, value that will be representing all categories.

Here is a designer code:

```
this.comboBox2.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.vRSTEPROBLEMABindingSource, "NAZIV", true));
        this.comboBox2.DataSource = this.vRSTEPROBLEMABindingSource1;
        this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "NAZIV";
        this.comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 51);
        this.comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
        this.comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(173, 21);
        this.comboBox2.TabIndex = 4;
        this.comboBox2.Text = "Svi";
        this.comboBox2.ValueMember = "NAZIV";
```

Comment: You will need to add default value to binding source before you set it as data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, there is no way to add items to `combobox` that are data bound. What you can do is fill items into a `List` then add them to the combobox. Here is a code:

```
            // your connection string + open connection
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(global::IssueTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            // data adapter
            OracleDataAdapter oa = new OracleDataAdapter("select naziv from vrsteproblema", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            oa.Fill(ds, "vrsteproblema");

            // put entries into a list
            List<string> comboNazivi = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["vrsteproblema"].Rows)
            {
                comboNazivi.Add(row["naziv"].ToString());
            }

            // add custom entry
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Svi");
            // fill the rest from the list
            for (var i = 0; i < comboNazivi.Count; i++) {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(comboNazivi[i]);
            }

            // dont forget to close conn
            conn.Close();
```